# R: user-defined function issue with apply

Tags: r, apply

I have 2 files.

"increment.tab"

```
grp   increment
1   10
2   25
3   35
4   50
```

"input.tab"

```
grp   pos
1   10
1   14
1   25
2   3
2   20
3   2
3   10
```

I am trying to apply an increment to column 2 of 'input.tab' as follows for example:

```
if grp=1, then increment=0
if grp=2, then increment=10
if grp=3, then increment=10+25=35
if grp=4, then increment=10+25+35=70
...
```

in order to get this output:

```
grp   pos   pos_adj
1   10   10
1   14   14
1   25   25
2   3   13
2   20   30
3   2   37
3   10   45
```

My plan is to use `apply` to process the input file row by row:

```
ref <- read.table("increment.tab", header=T, sep="\t")
input <- read.table("input.tab", header=T, sep="\t")

my_fun <- function(x, y){
   if(x==1){
      inc=0
   }
   else{
      inc=sum(ref[1:match(x, ref$grp)-1,2])
   }
   result = y + inc
   return(result)
}

input$pos_adj = apply(input, 1, my_fun(input$grp, input$pos))
```

But I get this error message that I cannot really understand.

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'my_fun(input$grp, input$pos)' is not a function, character or symbol
In addition: Warning message:
In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why 'my_fun' is not considered a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `apply` is failing because your third argument to it is the result from a function call, not a function itself. Further more, though it can work given your rudimentary data, if there are any other data types in your data.frame, it will fail since `apply` converts the data.frame into a `matrix`, which will result in type-conversions. It is because of this (and a few other reasons) that I recommend against using `apply` here.

I think you can vectorize it fairly easily, and the trick to bring in the `grp`-based additions can be resolved with `merge`. (It can also be done with `dplyr::left_join`.)

Your data:

```
increment <- read.table(text = "grp   increment
1   10
2   25
3   35
4   50", header = TRUE)

input <- read.table(text = "grp   pos
1   10
1   14
1   25
2   3
2   20
3   2
3   10", header = TRUE)
```

I'll update this so that the adjustments are based on the `$increment` column. You can *replace* `$increment` instead of *adding* `$add`, over to you.

```
increment$add <- c(0, cumsum(increment$increment[-nrow(increment)]))
increment
#   grp increment add
# 1   1        10   0
# 2   2        25  10
# 3   3        35  35
# 4   4        50  70

x <- merge(input, increment[,c("grp", "add")], by = "grp")
x
#   grp pos add
# 1   1  10   0
# 2   1  14   0
# 3   1  25   0
# 4   2   3  10
# 5   2  20  10
# 6   3   2  35
# 7   3  10  35
```

From here, it's simply a matter of adjusting. Both of these are

```
x$pos_adj <- x$pos + x$add
x$add <- NULL # remove the now-unnecessary column
x
#   grp pos pos_adj
# 1   1  10      10
# 2   1  14      14
# 3   1  25      25
# 4   2   3      13
# 5   2  20      30
# 6   3   2      37
# 7   3  10      45
```

(I've been a bit verbose with columns and such. This can certainly be made a little more compact, but I wanted there to be room for understanding what is being done and where.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do that using `case_when` from `dplyr`. I did not use your increment.tab because the numbers do not match your example.

**dplyr version 0.5.0**

```
library(dplyr)
input.tab%>%
  mutate(pos_adj=case_when(.$grp==1 ~ .$pos+0,
                           .$grp==2 ~ .$pos+10,
                           .$grp==3 ~ .$pos+35,
                           .$grp==4 ~ .$pos+70))

  grp pos pos_adj
1   1  10      10
2   1  14      14
3   1  25      25
4   2   3      13
5   2  20      30
6   3   2      37
7   3  10      45
```

**dplyr version 0.7.0**

```
library(dplyr)
input.tab%>%
  mutate(pos_adj=case_when(grp==1 ~ pos+0,
                           grp==2 ~ pos+10,
                           grp==3 ~ pos+35,
                           grp==4 ~ pos+70))
```

**Data**

```
input.tab <- read.table(text="grp   pos
1   10
1   14
1   25
2   3
2   20
3   2
3   10",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a vector to lookup values from

```
vec = setNames(object = c(0, 10, 35, 70), nm = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
vec
# 1  2  3  4 
# 0 10 35 70
```

Then, lookup the appropriate values from `vec` and add to `pos`. Using **P Lapointe's** data

```
increment.tab$pos + vec[match(increment.tab$grp, names(vec))]
# 1  1  1  2  2  3  3 
#10 14 25 13 30 37 45
```

Comment: I think I prefer this use of `match` as a lookup, as it allows you to set `nomatch=-Inf` (for example) for when the `grp` lookup fails. My `merge` answer would produce `NA` with extra work required to fix/change.

Comment: Thanks d.b ! Works great

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but as @r2evans explained your function call is problematic, and `apply` uses matrices. Their solution is a good one, but in case you still want to use your function, you just need to modify its application slightly and use `adply` from the `plyr` library. Using your example `ref` and `input` data frames as above, and without changing your function itself at all:

```
new_df <- adply(input, 1, function(df){
  c(pos_adj = my_fun(df$grp, df$pos))
})

> new_df
  grp pos pos_adj
1   1  10      10
2   1  14      14
3   1  25      25
4   2   3      13
5   2  20      30
6   3   2      37
7   3  10      45
```

If you are wanting to stick with `apply`, you could go this route (again, without changing your function):

```
input$pos_adj <- apply(input, 1, function(df){
  my_fun(df["grp"], df["pos"])
})

> input
  grp pos pos_adj
1   1  10      10
2   1  14      14
3   1  25      25
4   2   3      13
5   2  20      30
6   3   2      37
7   3  10      45
```

Comment: Thanks Luke C for the explanation and for keeping my function. I understand my mistake now.